# Files to add to a git repository

Tags: git

I have a repository hosted on GitHub and I'm wondering which files should be pushed to it. Obviously my source files are added to it, but I'm not sure what to do about the libraries I'm using.

For example, I use [this](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api) in my project. It's stored at `/lib/` in my project directory. Should I include `/lib/` in my repository?

Comment: In general, you should not include any files that can be generated programmatically.

Comment: Also, if you want, you can include that as a git submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dependency management/build tool like Jenkins, npm, ant+ivy, etc... Then include that configuration and instructions. You want to make the barrier to contribution as low as possible. Even asking folks to download and coordinate versions themselves can be off putting. If I have the choice of contributing to two similar projects I will pick the one with a nice build system and dep management over the one that has none. Also include unit-tests =)

Since you appear to be using java, here is an example from a project I help with:

https://github.com/vngx/vngx-jsch

Answer (score 1):

You should give instructions to users to let them download the latest version (or you can specify a tested-OK version) of 3rd party libraries, so that you won't violate the licenses of other 3rd party libraries ( some of them won't allow you to re-distribute / bundle in other software ).

Comment: Yeah - and it also depends on the library.  For instance, you should almost never add any standard libraries - but if some library is not normally installed on your average user's machine, is very difficult to build, not too big in size and its license allows it, then providing a binary version may be the best thing to do - in addition to instructions on how to build another version.